# Explanation of LidarBoost Algorithm?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to understand the LidarBoost algorithm as explained in [this paper](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~theobalt/cvpr09_superresolution.pdf) (PDF warning). My apologies if this isn't the appropriate exchange; I've posted in DSP, but I didn't get a response there, and the FAQ said that some image processing algorithms are acceptable here.

I don't understand how they take the original depth-images $Y_k$ and transform them into the up-sampled images $D_k$. I get how optical flow is used to align the $Y_k$ into a chosen reference frame, but is the transform between $Y_k$ and $D_k$ just a standard image up-sampling with nearest neighbors for the "interpolation" step? If that's the case, can someone explain how they get the term $W_k$ in their data term of the energy function? They say this about it, but I don't understand how to construct $W_k$ for each $k$:

> $W_k \in \mathbb{R}^{\beta n x \beta m}$ is a banded matrix that
>   encodes the positions of $D_k$ which one samples from during
>   resampling on the high-resolution target grid

I'm trying (so far frustratingly ineffectively) to get enough of a sense of the algorithm to try to implement it.

Comment: I'm redoing some similar experiments recently and have met with a lot of questions too.
To my understanding, the author applied the NN interpolation to x,y,z matrix respectively (you can find their raw data in this link: http://gvv.mpi-inf.mpg.de/files/old_site_files/tof/#upsampling).
But I'm still confused about how to configure Wk. If you have some new ideas. I really appreciate to discuss with you.